# Installing psycopg2 command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, django, postgresql, terminal

I'm trying to install psycopg2 but 
`pip install psycopg2`  brings to error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command line tools are installed

MacOS 10.15

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message?

Comment: Install using the binary directly

    pip install psycopg2-binary

Answer (score 4):

This is likely because you don't have the PostgreSQL devel library installed. You have a few options:

(1) Install the binary with `pip install psycopg2-binary`
(2) Install PostgreSQL with HomeBrew: `brew install postgresql`, then `pip install psycopg2`.

You can probably just install the binary.

Answer (score 0):

after updating the pip package error went away

To Update python3 pip package

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
 
/usr/bin/python3 get-pip.py
```