# Install psycopg2 on pypy3 docker image

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, pypy

I tried very hard to install psycopg2 on pypy3 docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/pypy

This proved impossible...

```
FROM pypy:3
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev gcc
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
RUN pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pypy3 -mpip install psycopg2            <-- Blow up here
RUN pypy3 -mpip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/src"
ENTRYPOINT ["pypy3", "xxx.py"]
```

Error message is:

```
api_gateway_1         |   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 793, in dbapi
api_gateway_1         |     import psycopg2
api_gateway_1         | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

esql -I/usr/include/postgresql/13/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
#8 1044.6     In file included from psycopg/typecast.c:168:
#8 1044.6     ./psycopg/typecast_datetime.c: In function ‘_parse_inftz’:
#8 1044.6     ./psycopg/typecast_datetime.c:116:14: error: ‘PyDateTime_TimeZone_UTC’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘PyDateTime_Time’?
#8 1044.6       116 |     tzinfo = PyDateTime_TimeZone_UTC;
#8 1044.6           |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 1044.6           |              PyDateTime_Time
#8 1044.6     ./psycopg/typecast_datetime.c:116:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
#8 1044.6     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried different things, none of them worked.
https://blog.csdn.net/cdnight/article/details/52536451
https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/ask/119621
[Installing psycopg2 command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790217/installing-psycopg2-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

In the end, I managed (Reluctantly), by switching to anaconda as base image:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/src"
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "xxx.py"]
```

Note, these in dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
```

They are all for sqlalchemy, which depends on psycopg2, which depends on configparser:

```
configparser
psycopg2
sqlalchemy
```

It worked. But I really want pypy3.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `psycopg2` is not compatible with PyPy.  You may want to try out https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2cffi/ instead.

Comment: Thanks Armin. Mattip below seems to suggest latest pypy3.7-v7.3.5 or above can do it?

Comment: No, he says v7.3.6 is needed.  He also recommends psycopg2cffi for performance reasons anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That docker image is using PyPy3.7-v7.3.5, you need at least v7.3.6 in order to use pycopg2. You can file an issue with the [docker source repo](https://github.com/docker-library/pypy/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed) which is not maintained by the PyPy team. You probably want to use the cffi variant since it should be faster. I would recommend you use the conda-packaged PyPy3.7, it already has binary packages for psycopy2 and many other packages, for linux and windows

```
conda create -n pypy37 pypy
```